# Unclear purpose of a class derived from Keras' BatchNormalization

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, object-detection, yolov4

I'm reading the code of a Keras implementation of YOLOv4 object detector.
It uses a custom Batch Norm layer, like this:

```
class BatchNormalization(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization):
    """
    "Frozen state" and "inference mode" are two separate concepts.
    `layer.trainable = False` is to freeze the layer, so the layer will use
    stored moving `var` and `mean` in the "inference mode", and both `gama`
    and `beta` will not be updated !
    """
    def call(self, x, training=False):
        if not training:
            training = tf.constant(False)
        training = tf.logical_and(training, self.trainable)
        return super().call(x, training)
```

Even though I understand how the usual Batch Norm layer works during training and inference, I don't understand the comment nor the need for this modification. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Usually (in another types of layers) freeze training of the layer doesn't necessarily mean that the layer is run in inference mode.
Inference mode is normally controller by the training argument.
In the case of batchnorm layer, when the layer is freeze we want that not only the layer parameters will not modify during the training process, we want addionaly that the model will use the moving mean and the moving variance to normalize the current batch, rather than using the mean and variance of the current batch.

So despite the difference between a layer training freeze and an inference mode that is common. In the case of the batchnorm there is more similarity between the two modes.
In both, we want that in addition to freezing the parameters of the layer the model used the general mean and standard deviation and will not be affected by the current batch statistics.
(It's important for the stability of the model).

From [BatchNormalization layer guide - Keras](https://keras.io/api/layers/normalization_layers/batch_normalization/)

**About setting layer.trainable = False on a BatchNormalization layer:**

**Freezing a layer in all the types of layers:**
The meaning of setting layer.trainable = False is to freeze the layer, i.e. its internal state will not change during training: **its trainable weights will not be updated during fit()** or train_on_batch(), and its state updates will not be run.

**additional behavior when freezing a batchnorm layer:**
However, in the case of the BatchNormalization layer, setting trainable = False on the layer means that the layer will be **subsequently run in inference mode** (**meaning that it will use the moving mean and the moving variance to normalize the current batch**, rather than using the mean and variance of the current batch).

Comment: ok, so how the new batchnorm layer is different?